# slicing numpy array along an arbitrary dimension

Tags: python, numpy

say that I have a (40,20,30) numpy array and that I have a function that after some work will return half of the input array along a selected input axis. Is there an automatic way to do so ? I would like to avoid such an ugly code:

```
def my_function(array,axis=0):

    ...

    if axis == 0:
        return array[:array.shape[0]/2,:,:] --> (20,20,30) array
    elif axis = 1:
        return array[:,:array.shape[1]/2,:] --> (40,10,30) array
    elif axis = 2: 
        return array[:,:,:array.shape[2]/2] --> (40,20,15) array
```

thanks for your help

Eric

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use `np.split` for this [[docs]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html), and simply take the first or second element returned, depending on which one you want.  For example:

```
>>> a = np.random.random((40,20,30))
>>> np.split(a, 2, axis=0)[0].shape
(20, 20, 30)
>>> np.split(a, 2, axis=1)[0].shape
(40, 10, 30)
>>> np.split(a, 2, axis=2)[0].shape
(40, 20, 15)
>>> (np.split(a, 2, axis=0)[0] == a[:a.shape[0]/2, :,:]).all()
True
```

Comment: FYI: split() also takes a tuple specifying arbitrary split points.

Answer (score 4):

thanks for your help, DSM. I will use your approach.

In the meantime, I found a (dirty ?) hack:

```
>>> a = np.random.random((40,20,30))
>>> s = [slice(None),]*a.ndim
>>> s[axis] = slice(f,l,s)
>>> a1 = a[s]
```

Perhaps a bit more general than np.split but much less elegant !

Comment: This is not less elegant. This just removes some of the syntactic sugar: `:` is `slice(None)`, `a:b:c` is `slice(a, b, c)`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.rollaxis` is a good tool for this:

```py
def my_func(array, axis=0):
    array = np.rollaxis(array, axis)
    out = array[:array.shape[0] // 2]
    # Do stuff with array and out knowing that the axis of interest is now 0
    ...

    # If you need to restore the order of the axes
    if axis == -1:
        axis = out.shape[0] - 1
    out = np.rollaxis(out, 0, axis + 1)
```